# How to create options button with ncurses

Tags: c, linux, colors, ncurses

EHLO

I am into C and ncurses on Linux for the creation of an installer and I am kinda new on this. I have seen installers for linux(especially Anaconda) that can display windows,  with buttons like "OK""NEXT""BACK" like on this link  https://hurley.files.wordpress.com/2008/01/snack-popcorn-snapshot.png?w=500 and I need some information about it, I have found menu examples but not too much about "buttons" as I call it.

Greetings.

Comment: Are you actually asking how we would create an installer, with an ncurses TUI?  Or are you asking specifically about programming with NCURSES in C? To simply create an installer, with an Ncurses backed TUI, the goto tool would be Dialog and shell.

Comment: I am trying to make a simple installer with ncurses now but I have seen Anaconda in non-graphical mode and I would like to make it like that I hope that ncurses contains buttons, checks, etc. Or maybe is better newt?

Comment: Dialog provides a library interface which lets one build applications like dialog. It also has documentation, e.g., http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html#documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example shown is from one of the slang-based applications such as whiptail.  Anaconda uses python scripts which load the [newt](https://fedorahosted.org/newt/) library and run those.  As far as I know, there is essentially no documentation for any of those (other than source code), and that is a longstanding issue, for instance this [comment](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/307162/), and [this](http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/any-examples-documentation-for-python-newt.718922/).

Whiptail is an application "like" dialog, but much simpler.  dialog is a curses-based application which can be run using shell-scripts (such as bash).  You can find more information about dialog on its [homepage](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well thank you guys.

I went to read some newt docs and it's amazing, actually is pretty simple and the official documentation is very straght-forward and it works, so I will better keep working my installer with newt instead of with ncurses.

Comment: Perhaps you found something more than this: http://gnewt.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html

Comment: That's the official doc that comes with the source and until now I haven't had any problems with it, pretty simple for what I need.

Comment: I asked, because it had not been updated since 1998 (aside from reformatting - see https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/newt.git/log/tutorial.sgml), and the library (and its interfaces) have changed.